# Method of Steepest descents - determining location of end points?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

When we do the method of steepest descents (aka the saddle point method) is there anyway to quickly determine if the two end points points are in opposite valleys of the saddle point? I know this can be done graphically using contour plots but I am looking for method which can (quickly) be done on paper. Most books I read on this topic seem to skip over this part and just assume that they are in different valleys - is this a reasonable assumption?

Comment: It is not an assumption you should make blindly. What the books assume is that you can show that the condition is met before applying the method. If you have a particular example in mind I could try to describe what my reasoning would be.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Ok thanks. The example I have been working on is:
$$I=\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(txi-t\ln(1+x^2)\right)dx\quad \text{as $t\rightarrow \infty$}$$

Comment: Ah, for that example it's best to just do it based on a contour plot. The new contour should travel straight up from $x=0$ into the upper half-plane, then turn right and rejoin the positive real axis somewhere. If you look at the contour plot, you can see it's possible to do this so that the highest point of $\operatorname{Re}(ix-\ln(1+x^2))$ on the contour is at $x=0$. If you really want, you can do some tedious analysis of the height at different points, but imo it's fine to just show a plot in this case.

Comment: What is 'quickly' seems to be primarily opinion-based.